# How to position close button in a Popup in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have a popup as given below. I'm trying to position a close button in the top right corner of the popup but there seems to be some extra space there that I can't get rid of.

I am also facing an error where when I press the OKAY button the popup doesn't get dismissed even though I am supplying it with a Navigator.pop(context).

This is my code:

```
class Popup {
  final String title;
  final String message;
  final String rightButton;
  final VoidCallback onTapRightButton;
  final String leftButton;
  final VoidCallback onTapLeftButton;
...

 show(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return _PopupCall(
            title: title,
            message: message,
            leftButton: leftButton ?? 'null',
            rightButton: rightButton,
            onTapLeftButton: onTapLeftButton,
            onTapRightButton: onTapRightButton);
      },
    );
  }
...

       @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return ScaleTransition(
              scale: scaleAnimation,
              child: AlertDialog(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(24),
                  ),
                ),
                title: Wrap(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.close,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              size: 25,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Text(widget.title,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'TTNorms',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                wordSpacing: 0,
                                letterSpacing: 0,
                                fontSize: 25,
                                color: Colors.yellow,
                              )),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                        Text(widget.message,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'TTNorms',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              wordSpacing: 0,
                              letterSpacing: 0,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                            )),
                        const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Visibility(
                              visible: widget.leftButton != 'null',
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      if (widget.leftButton != 'null') {
                                        widget
                                            .onTapLeftButton(); //function to be performed onTap
                                      }
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 40,
                                      width: 80,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          border: Border.all(
                                              color: Colors.yellow, width: 2.0),
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(25),
                                          ),
                                          color: Colors.blue),
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text('Okay',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: 'TTNorms',
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              wordSpacing: 0,
                                              letterSpacing: 0,
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              color: Colors.yellow,
                                            )),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: 10.0,
                                left: 10,
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    widget
                                        .onTapRightButton(); //function to be performed onTap
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 40,
                                    width: 80,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(15),
                                      ),
                                      gradient: kGradientBackground,
                                    ),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text(widget.rightButton.toUpperCase(),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'TTNorms',
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            wordSpacing: 0,
                                            letterSpacing: 0,
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: Colors.blue,
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
```

This is what the popup looks like:

[image]

This is how I'm calling my popup:

```
Popup(
        title: 'Oops!',
        message:
            "Looks like there has been a mistake please check later!",
        rightButton: 'OK',
        onTapLeftButton: () {},
        onTapRightButton: () {},
      ).show(context);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Flutter Inspector [image], you will understand the structure of your Popup Dialog:

[image]

The position of the close icon is defined by the `AlertDialog`'s `titlePadding` in dark blue and the `IconButton`padding in lighter blue. If you set the `titlePadding` to zero, you might have the position you want for the close Icon:

[image]
[image]

However, now, the content of your AlertDialog is too close to the border of the dialog's frame. I suggest moving the content of the Dialog to the `content` field instead of having everything inside the `title`:

[image]

You could go one step further by moving the action buttons to the `actions` field of your `AlertDialog`.

### Full Source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => Popup(
            title: 'Oops!',
            message: "Looks like there has been a mistake please check later!",
            leftButton: 'Cancel',
            rightButton: 'OK',
            onTapLeftButton: () {},
            onTapRightButton: () {},
          ).show(context),
          child: Text('SHOW POPUP'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Popup {
  final String title;
  final String message;
  final String rightButton;
  final VoidCallback onTapRightButton;
  final String leftButton;
  final VoidCallback onTapLeftButton;

  Popup({
    this.title,
    this.message,
    this.rightButton,
    this.onTapRightButton,
    this.leftButton,
    this.onTapLeftButton,
  });

  show(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return _PopupCall(
            title: title,
            message: message,
            leftButton: leftButton,
            rightButton: rightButton,
            onTapLeftButton: onTapLeftButton,
            onTapRightButton: onTapRightButton);
      },
    );
  }
}

class _PopupCall extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String message;
  final String rightButton;
  final VoidCallback onTapRightButton;
  final String leftButton;
  final VoidCallback onTapLeftButton;

  const _PopupCall(
      {Key key,
      this.title,
      this.message,
      this.rightButton,
      this.onTapRightButton,
      this.leftButton,
      this.onTapLeftButton})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PopupCallState createState() => _PopupCallState();
}

class _PopupCallState extends State<_PopupCall> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(24),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      title: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.close,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 25,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(widget.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'TTNorms',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  wordSpacing: 0,
                  letterSpacing: 0,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(
            widget.message,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'TTNorms',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              wordSpacing: 0,
              letterSpacing: 0,
              fontSize: 15,
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      actions: [
        if (widget.leftButton != null)
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  widget.onTapLeftButton?.call();
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 80,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow, width: 2.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(25),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Okay',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'TTNorms',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        wordSpacing: 0,
                        letterSpacing: 0,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: 10.0,
            left: 10,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                widget.onTapRightButton?.call();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 80,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(15),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    widget.rightButton.toUpperCase(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'TTNorms',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      wordSpacing: 0,
                      letterSpacing: 0,
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Note, I could not reproduce the problem with not dismissing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your class to retrieve a function from Stateful Widget. Pass your `Navigator.pop(context)` action to that function when showing your popup. Inside the popup class, use that passed function to dismiss itself.